# MySQL Query of Cumulative Sum (Case: when there is no order on such period, the value still on previous period)

Tags: mysql, cumulative-sum

I have order table with order date of course and its amount.

I want to sum the amount of previous period with current period and resulting table like this

[my current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeZzM.png)

the query I have tried was

```
    with data as(
select  
        lead_id,
        no_pks,
        customer_name,
        point_name,
        funder_id,
        DATE_FORMAT(order_date,'%Y-%m') as year_and_month_order,
        sum(total_amount) as outstanding
    from 
        mall_order_list_payment
    group by
        lead_id,
        no_pks,
        customer_name,
        point_name,
        funder_id,
        year_and_month_order
)

select 
    *,
    sum(outstanding) over(partition by lead_id,no_pks order by year_and_month_order) as cumulative_outstanding
from
    data
order by lead_id,no_pks
```

My goals is when on such month there were no order, the amount  are 0 while the cumulative amount must be followed the previous month. The result of what I need are

[My goals result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHDgc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add one more recursive CTE and generate base dates list (calendar) using min. and max. dates from your data table as generated range borders (or set these borders as parameters) then LEFT JOIN your table to it. In window function you'd use the dates from this base table which will contain all needed dates.

Simple DEMO:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (the_date DATE, the_value INT);
> INSERT INTO test 
> SELECT '2022-03-04', 1 UNION ALL
> SELECT '2022-03-05', 2 UNION ALL
> SELECT '2022-03-07', 3 ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *, SUM(the_value) OVER (ORDER BY the_date) cumulative
> FROM test;
> ```
>
> | the_date | the_value | cumulative |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2022-03-04 | 1 | 1 |
> | 2022-03-05 | 2 | 3 |
> | 2022-03-07 | 3 | 6 |

> ```
> WITH RECURSIVE
> cte AS (
>     SELECT MIN(the_date) the_date
>     FROM test
>     UNION ALL
>     SELECT the_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
>     FROM cte
>     WHERE the_date < ( SELECT MAX(the_date)
>                        FROM test )
> )
> SELECT *, SUM(test.the_value) OVER (ORDER BY the_date) cumulative
> FROM cte
> LEFT JOIN test USING (the_date);
> ```
>
> | the_date | the_value | cumulative |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2022-03-04 | 1 | 1 |
> | 2022-03-05 | 2 | 3 |
> | 2022-03-06 | *null* | 3 |
> | 2022-03-07 | 3 | 6 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7a7f9df60d90acd4456c8dd92fe0f584)*

---

The variant for different `id` values

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (id INT, the_date DATE, the_value INT);
> INSERT INTO test 
> SELECT 1, '2022-03-04', 1 UNION ALL
> SELECT 1, '2022-03-05', 2 UNION ALL
> SELECT 1, '2022-03-07', 3 UNION ALL
> SELECT 2, '2022-03-04', 4 UNION ALL
> SELECT 2, '2022-03-06', 5 UNION ALL
> SELECT 2, '2022-03-08', 6 ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *, SUM(the_value) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY the_date) cumulative
> FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | the_date   | the_value | cumulative
> -: | :--------- | --------: | ---------:
>  1 | 2022-03-04 |         1 |          1
>  1 | 2022-03-05 |         2 |          3
>  1 | 2022-03-07 |         3 |          6
>  2 | 2022-03-04 |         4 |          4
>  2 | 2022-03-06 |         5 |          9
>  2 | 2022-03-08 |         6 |         15
> ```

> ```
> WITH RECURSIVE
> cte1 AS (
>     SELECT MIN(the_date) the_date
>     FROM test
>     UNION ALL
>     SELECT the_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
>     FROM cte1
>     WHERE the_date < ( SELECT MAX(the_date)
>                        FROM test )
> ),
> cte2 AS ( 
>     SELECT DISTINCT id
>     FROM test
> )
> SELECT *, SUM(test.the_value) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY the_date) cumulative
> FROM cte1
> CROSS JOIN cte2
> LEFT JOIN test USING (id, the_date);
> ```
>
> ```
> the_date   | id | the_value | cumulative
> :--------- | -: | --------: | ---------:
> 2022-03-04 |  1 |         1 |          1
> 2022-03-05 |  1 |         2 |          3
> 2022-03-06 |  1 |      null |          3
> 2022-03-07 |  1 |         3 |          6
> 2022-03-08 |  1 |      null |          6
> 2022-03-04 |  2 |         4 |          4
> 2022-03-05 |  2 |      null |          4
> 2022-03-06 |  2 |         5 |          9
> 2022-03-07 |  2 |      null |          9
> 2022-03-08 |  2 |         6 |         15
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=de8db3bd54347ced63293b36af34bf64)*

Comment: how if I want to see parameter with id as criteria? perhaps you know that I want to cumulative per id. the min and max date should be different of each id, CMIIW?

Comment: @NandaRukmana *I want to cumulative per id* Add one more CTE which gets distinct `id` values. Cross join it with calendar - and this will be a base which contains all pairs id-date for all ids and all dates, including ones non-present in your data. And of course add according PARTITION BY.

Comment: could you show me the simple query for example like you did before, please Mr. Akina?. Honestly I am new with sql in the real case